# Styles for active page in React JhiPagination component

Tags: reactjs, pagination, jhipster

JhiPagination is abstract component generated with jhipster. it does have a activePage prop that I defined just like the default generated entity page does, but the resulted pagination doesn't have the current active page class like as shown on the picture.

Did anyone encounter such limitation before?

[image: pagination probleme]

```
<JhiPagination
    items={getPaginationItemsNumber(totalStreamsGateways, size)}
    activePage={ activePage + 1 }
    onSelect={this.handlePagination}
    maxButtons={5}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 0.9, the component doesn't contain any code to highlight the active page.

The component comes from `react-jhipster`. In the [source code](https://github.com/jhipster/react-jhipster/blob/master/src/component/pagination/pagination.tsx), you can see that the `activePage` props is only used to:

- compute which page numbers should be displayed;
- enable or disable the first page, previous, next and last page links.

Comment: So it s not possible to add this feature to my current project with jhipster pagination?

Comment: No, you have to develop your own component (you can start from the source code of JhiPagination).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time sir.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was overriding the original component and create my own pagination class as below.

custom-pagination.tsx

```
import {JhiItemCount, JhiPagination} from "react-jhipster";
import {PaginationItem, PaginationLink} from 'reactstrap';

class CustomPagination extends JhiPagination {
  displayPaginationItem = i => {
    const {activePage} = this.props;
    return (
      <PaginationItem className={activePage === i + 1 ? " current" : ''} key={i}>
        <PaginationLink onClick={this.updateActivePage(i + 1)}>
          {i + 1}
        </PaginationLink>
      </PaginationItem>
    )
  };
}
```

custom-pagination.css

```
.current .page-link {
    /* your style on active element */
}
```

Finally, I used `<CustomPagination />` component instead of `<JhiPagnination />`